# qsort with key value pairs

Tags: c, qsort

I am using the C library function qsort to sort a bunch of integer keys. Any ideas, suggestions, pointers on how I can extend it to sort key-value pairs, where the integer keys can have any associated value? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `struct { int key; void *value; }` and a function that does the comparison?

Answer (score 4):

Use an array of (fixed sized) structs, and supply your own comparison functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
//just quick sorting function (with key-index array to maintain identity)
//inefficient but works
void quicksort(int *values, int *keys, int count)
{
    bool bool_sorted = false;
    int temp;

    //check whether all keys are in the correct order
    while (bool_sorted == false)
    {
        bool_sorted = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < count-1; i++)
        {
            //if next value is lower
            if (values[i] > values[i+1])
            {
                //swap + key index
                temp = values[i];
                values[i] = values[i+1];
                values[i+1] = temp;

                temp = keys[i];
                keys[i] = keys[i+1];
                keys[i+1] = temp;

                bool_sorted = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Posted for convenience of anyone else looking for an actual answer.